# Problem with deriving uniformly powerful test

Tags: statistics, parametric, density-function, hypothesis-testing

Let's consider discrete variable $X$ with the following distribution for $\Theta = \{0, 1\}$:

$$f(x;0) = (0.420, 0.054, 0.526)$$
$$f(x;1) = (0.046, 0.239, 0.715)$$

I want to derive uniformly powerful test for it with $H_0: \theta = 0, H_1: \theta =  1$

My intuitive problem is the following: I know that critical region is in form of

$$R = \{X: \frac{f_1(X)}{f_0(X)} > k\}$$

where $k$ is chosen in such a way that $P(f(X; 0) > f(X; 1)) = \alpha$

However this likelihood for $\theta = 0$ equals to $0.42 \cdot 0.054 \cdot 0.526 = 0.01192968$ and for $\theta = 1$ we have $0.046 \cdot 0.239 \cdot 0.715 =  0.00786071$ so it does not depend on theta, and probability $P(f(X; 0) > f(X; 1)) = 1$.

Can you please point mistake in my way of thinking?

**EDIT**

I must say that I have hard time understating the answer. One of the main things that I don't understand is that $c$ is picked three times  differently, whereas to my knowledge $c$ should be picked as such a number that satisfies:

$$P_{\theta = 0}(f_1(x) > c f_0(x) = \alpha)$$

Now we know that $f_1(x) = \prod_{i = 1}^n f(x_i, 1)$ and $f_0(x) = \prod_{i = 1}^n f(x_i, 0)$

Could you please correct where I'm thinking incorrectly?

Comment: Why are you multiplying the three numbers in $0.42 \cdot 0.054 \cdot 0.526 = 0.01192968$ and  $0.046 \cdot 0.239 \cdot 0.715 =  0.00786071$?

Comment: Hey Henry! I edited my question! Hope its clear now

Answer (score 1):

The assumptions of Neymann-Pearson are satisfied, so there exists a UMP test of the form
$$T(X)=\begin{cases}
1&f(X,1)>cf(X,0)\\
\gamma & f(X,1)=cf(X,0)\\
0&f(X,1)<cf(X,0)
\end{cases}$$
where $\gamma \in [0,1]$ and $c\geq 0$ s.t. $E_0[T(X)]=\alpha$. Suppose we have a single random sample $X=X_1\in \{1,2,3\}$.
$$\frac{f(x_1,1)}{f(x_1,0)}=\frac{p_{1,1}}{p_{1,0}}\mathbf{1}_{\{1\}}(x_1)+
\frac{p_{2,1}}{p_{2,0}}\mathbf{1}_{\{2\}}(x_1)+\frac{p_{3,1}}{p_{3,0}}\mathbf{1}_{\{3\}}(x_1)$$
From the data, we know that:
$$\frac{p_{1,1}}{p_{1,0}}<\frac{p_{3,1}}{p_{3,0}}<\frac{p_{2,1}}{p_{2,0}}$$
Set $A(c)=\{x:f(x,1)>cf(x,0)\},\,E(c)=\{x:f(x,1)=cf(x,0)\}$. Suppose
$$c=p_{1,1}/p_{1,0}$$
We get
$$\begin{aligned}P_0(f(X,1)>cf(X,0))
&=p_{1,0}\mathbf{1}_{A(c)}(1)+p_{2,0}\mathbf{1}_{A(c)}(2)+p_{3,0}\mathbf{1}_{A(c)}(3)=\\
&=p_{2,0}+p_{3,0}\end{aligned}$$
and
$$P_0(f(X,1)=cf(X,0))=p_{1,0}\mathbf{1}_{E(c)}(1)+p_{2,0}\mathbf{1}_{E(c)}(2)+p_{3,0}\mathbf{1}_{E(c)}(3)=p_{1,0}$$
therefore
$$E_0[T(X)]=p_{2,0}+p_{3,0}+\gamma p_{1,0}=\alpha$$
set
$$\gamma^*=\frac{\alpha-p_{2,0}-p_{3,0}}{p_{1,0}}\geq 0\implies \alpha \geq p_{2,0}+p_{3,0}$$
So if $\alpha \geq p_{2,0}+p_{3,0}$ this is the UMP test. Suppose now
$$c=p_{3,1}/p_{3,0}$$
We get
$$\begin{aligned}P_0(f(X,1)>cf(X,0))
&=p_{1,0}\mathbf{1}_{A(c)}(1)+p_{2,0}\mathbf{1}_{A(c)}(2)+p_{3,0}\mathbf{1}_{A(c)}(3)=\\
&=p_{2,0}\end{aligned}$$
and
$$P_0(f(X,1)=cf(X,0))=p_{1,0}\mathbf{1}_{E(c)}(1)+p_{2,0}\mathbf{1}_{E(c)}(2)+p_{3,0}\mathbf{1}_{E(c)}(3)=p_{3,0}$$
therefore
$$E_0[T(X)]=p_{2,0}+\gamma p_{3,0}=\alpha $$
set
$$\gamma^*=\frac{\alpha-p_{2,0}}{p_{3,0}}$$
we get
$$0\leq \gamma^*\leq 1\implies p_{2,0}\leq \alpha \leq p_{2,0}+p_{3,0}$$
so if $p_{2,0}\leq \alpha \leq p_{2,0}+p_{3,0}$ this is the UMP test. In conclusion:
$$c=p_{2,1}/p_{2,0}$$
We get $P_0(f(X,1)>cf(X,0))=0$ and
$$P_0(f(X,1)=cf(X,0))=p_{2,0}\implies \gamma^*=\alpha/p_{2,0}$$
$$\gamma^*\leq 1 \implies \alpha \leq p_{2,0}$$
So here we have finally the values for $(c,\gamma)$ for all levels of $\alpha$.

Comment: Hey Snoop thank you very much for your answer! Could you please have a look at my updated question?

Comment: @Lucian Neymann-Pearson states that for every $\alpha$ there exists a UMP with size $\alpha$ and the form above. The UMP test parameters can depend on $\alpha$